# VS - Android - How to apply a style to main activity

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-activity, android-manifest

Just need to clarify what should I name, where and how exactly in order to apply a custom style to the main activity.

I want to apply a custom style "Theme.Transparent" to the main activity from the CustomStyles.xml file. To do it you should add the following section to the AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity android:name="???" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/> // see main question about this
```

I have no idea what name should be there and how it corresponds to other names in the app (see my main question about this). I found a few places where you specify activity name. I marked these places in the code as 1, 2, 3, 4 (see other questions about each number)

In **MainActivity.cs**:

```
namespace CustomName // 1
{
    [Activity(Name = "???" Label = "CustomName", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")] // 2
    public class MainActivity : Activity // 3
    {
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application android:label="CustomName"> // 4
    <activity android:name="ActivityName"> // 5
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Now questions**

**Main question**: Should I add **activity** section in AndroidManifest.xml for the main activity to apply a custom style to it? What name should main activity have there? If I add the **activity** section there and give it a name, where else should I use this name to make this style work with this activity? It's mess with names

Code 1) Application namespace name should be the application name literally?

Code 2) [Activity] Name and Label tags, what are they for and how should I name it?

Code 3) public class MainActivity, does this name matter for styling?

Code 4) what is this for?

Code 5) see main question

How is it all connected?

**EDITS for Joe LV's answer**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="Custom Application Name"> // this name does not appear in the phone anyway
</application>
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    ...
  </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
namespace CustomName
{
    [Activity(Name = "CustomName.MainActivity", Label = "Custom Activity Name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@styles/Theme.Transparent")] // the phone application receives name from this label
```

Q1) Error in AndroidManifest.xml "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@styles/Theme.Transparent')" **Answer: remove s from "styles" in "@styles/Theme.Transparent"**

Q2) The application in the phone receives the name from main activity label, not from the application label. What is the application label for and why the app itself gets the name of activity?

Comment: The `<activity android:name>` value should match your `class` name that is a subclass of `Activity`. There is no need to add your own section to `AndroidManifest.xml` if you are using the `[Activity]` attribute as it will generate the entry at build time. You can use the `[Activity Name=]` to specify a name.

Comment: A `subclass` is a class that inherits another one. Thus in your example would be your `MainActivity`

Comment: No I did not mean that. MainActivity is a subclass of Activity. Your error is because you have an `s` on `styles` when the proper usage is `style`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: As you might realise by now: we find vandalism almost the instant it's done and we will revert it every single time. Please stop making more work for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 1) The application name can be changed by changing the label of application in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, like this: `<application android:label="MyName">`, so you app's name has changed to "MyName" which you can see in your phone screen and your application namespace still is `CustomName`.

Code 2) [Activity] `Name` and `Label` tags, both of them can be changed by yourself. The `Name` is the current Activity's name which can be used to start this activity explicitly, like @Jon has said, it should match your class name, and the `Label` is the current Activity's title which you can see it at the top of your activity.

Code 3) The `MainActivity`'s name does no matter to the style. You can custom it in your `styles.xml` file.

Code 4) Please refer to Code 1)

Code 5) Main question. Like @Jon has said, "There is no need to add your own section to AndroidManifest.xml if you are using the [Activity] attribute as it will generate the entry at build time."

Please put your style into [`styles.xml`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/) file not `CustomStyles.xml` file, and refer to it by `Theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"`. The activity name should be like this: `[Activity Name=package.TypeName]`, so in your code it should be `[Activity Name=CustomName.MainActivity]`.
Finally, your Activity attribute can be this:

`[Activity(Label = "YourName", MainLauncher = true,Name = "CustomName.MainActivity",Theme ="@style/Theme.Transparent")]`

### Update:

Q2)

- You app consists of many activities, every `Activity` has it's label and the label can be seen when this activity is `OnResume`. This will tell user where they are when they are using your app, so user won't be lost in your app.
- The `Application`'s label is your app's name, like "Facebook", "Google", etc.